# Knockout access to variable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have variable with some properties, and function
I'm trying to get to the properties, but this give me empty vars.
What can I do? for example:

```
    var exports = {

    city: ko.observable(),
    street: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, number:true}),

    back : function(){
       console.log(this.city);
    },
```

HTML

```
        <button data-bind="click: back" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
```

I'm also attached the full HTML and JS. on this, i cannot get this.myAcmout(). on respond function:

HTML

```
<div class="responses">
<div role="form" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">{{_t('Responses')}}</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">

            <div class="form-control-static" data-bind="visible: request.responses().length == 0">
                {{_t('No responses.')}}
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped table-hover col-sm-12"
                   data-bind="visible: request.responses().length > 0">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{_t('Created')}}</th>
                    <th>{{_t('Amount')}}</th>
                    <th>{{_t('Rate')}}</th>
                    <th>{{_t('Distance')}}</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: request.responses()">
                <tr class="clickable">
                    <td>{{since()}}</td>
                    <td>{{amount}}</td>
                    <td>{{rate}}</td>
                    <td>{{distance}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a data-bind="click: action">{{_t('Details')}}</a>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- ko if: !isRequestor -->
    <h5>{{_t('Your response')}}</h5>

    <div class="form-group" data-bind="css: { hideErrors: !hasBeenSubmittedOnce()}">

        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">{{_t('Amount')}}</label>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" id="myAmountInput" class="form-control" data-bind="'autoNumeric: myAmount'">
            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <p class="form-control-static">{{ request.requestedCurrency }}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->


</div>


<div class="x-btn-row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bind="visible: !isRequestor, click: respond">
        {{isResponder() ? _t('Update response') : _t('Respond')}}
    </button>
    <button data-bind="visible: isRequestor || isResponder(), click: cancel" class="btn btn-danger">{{_t('Cancel')
        }}</button>
    <button data-bind="click: back" class="btn btn-default">{{_t('Back')}}</button>

</div>
```

JS

```
define(['knockout', 'knockout-validation', 'services/changeup', 'moment', 'lodash', 'plugins/router'], function (ko, validation, changeup, moment, _, router) {

ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'error',
    errorMessageClass: 'help-inline '
});

function tick(){
    var request = exports.request;
    console.log('tick', request);
    if(request){
        request.endsIn(moment.utc(request.expiresAt).fromNow());
        _.each(request.responses(), function(rs){
            rs.since(moment.utc(rs.createdAt).fromNow());
        });
    }
}

function belongsToUserInfo(r){
    return r && exports.userInfo && r.username === exports.userInfo.username;
}

var timerId = setInterval(tick, 1000 * 10);

var exports = {

    isRequestor: undefined,

    myAmount: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, number:true}),

    isResponder: ko.observable(),

    request: undefined,

    userInfo: undefined,

    hasBeenSubmittedOnce : ko.observable(false),

    errors : ko.validation.group(this),

    action : function(){

    },

    back : function(){
    },

    cancel : function(){
    },

    respond: function(scope){
        console.log(this.myAmount());
        this.hasBeenSubmittedOnce(true);
        var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to give proposal? your current proposal is: " + exports.request.amount);
        if (r===true){
            if (!this.myAmount.isValid()){
                this.errors.showAllMessages();
            } else {
                changeup.respond(exports.request._id, exports.myAmount()).then(function(){
                    router.navigate('dashboard');
                });
            }
        }
    },

    activate: function (activationData) {
    }

};


return exports;
```

});

Comment: What are you getting, please show us the result

Comment: I'm just getting null

Comment: On this case? on my console. but I've tried on many ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the missing parenthesis (as other pointed out) I don't see a problem here. Can you post a fiddle with your complete code?

This one is working:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: city" />
<button data-bind="click: back" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>  


var exports = {
    city: ko.observable('Los Angeles'),
    street: ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        number: true
    }),

    back: function (data) {
        console.log(data.city());      
        // or
        console.log(this.city());
        console.log(this.city);//incorrect
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(exports);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/cdjbX/1/

Comment: I added the full code to my question. it look very bad on JSfiddle, becuse all of the strings...

Comment: So what property are you trying to access and from what function? How about a fiddle version of what you're trying to do?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with your autoNumeric binding handler. If you replace that with a regular value bindingHandler the respond button works.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where you are seeing the `null` value but i guess it can due to `this.city`. To access observable value, you should do something like this

```
  back : function(){
 console.log(this.city()); 
},
```

notice `()` at the end of `city`. One more thing, the other most common thing why people see irrelevant value is because they defined `this` in wrong scope.

You should call this `back` funciton in this way

```
<button data-bind="click: exports.back()" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
```

Comment: I tried use the city(), it didn't work to. Maybe the porlbem is on scope, but how should i get the right one?

Comment: updated the answer as per scoping logic. apply appropriately .

Comment: I cannot define var self = this in my export and if I'm writing self: this, so self get "window"

Comment: On this way self is "window"

Comment: yes. do that . You can do something like `self = this ; var a =  {b: ko.observable(12) , c: function() { console.log(this.b()) }  } ; a.c()`

Comment: On this case my self is "window"

Comment: if it defined globally then yes. would you please tell me how you are calling the `back` function ?

Comment: I'm getting error for that : Unable to process binding "click: function (){return exports.back() }